# Scale the gradient of the negative log-likelihood

Tags: likelihood, kalman-filter, gradient

I am using Discrete-time Unscented Kalman Filter **UKF** to directly approximate the log-likelihood and its gradient, to be used in the identification of my **continuous-discrete dynamic model**.

It is to be noted that all the simulations were carried out by MATLAB where the
true states of the my model are obtained by solving the continuous process equation using the Euler approximation with **0.1 s** as the integration time step.

Now my gradient return a value multiplied by **10** compared with the **central finite difference** of MATLAB, is there any relation between the integration time step and the gradient of the log-likelihood?. Because when I scale my gradient by **0.1** MATLAB accept the gradient when it check the derivative using `derivativecheck`.